# Error Installing MySQL Workbench

Tags: 14.04, mysql-workbench

I'm unable to install MySQL Workbench.
It tells the following error:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

mysql-workbench: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
                 Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 1:2.24.0) but 1:2.24.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libpcrecpp0 (>= 7.7) but 1:8.31-2ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is a virtual package
                 Depends: mysql-workbench-data (= 6.0.8+dfsg-2) but 6.0.8+dfsg-2 is to be nstalled
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHUXT.png)

How can I fix this? I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Are you still looking for answers?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install all the dependencies prior to installing MySQL Workbench.

Try out this command:
`sudo apt-get install libgcc1 libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libpcrecpp0 python mysql-workbench-data`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.5
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

I had the same problem, and I got it to work. I had to do it through the command line. I think what caused me this problem was that I did apt-get install mysql-client-5.6 before I installed any other mysql- stuff.

First `sudo apt-get update`
Then I tried to apt-get install mysql-workbench, but I got this error which told me the next step.

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created 
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-workbench : Depends: mysql-client
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I did `sudo apt-get install mysql-client` but it gave a similar error but told me I needed mysql-client-5.5. So I did `sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.5`, and it worked. Then I installed mysql-client, and it worked. Then I installed mysql-workbench, and it worked!

P.S. Props to Sanchit. The first thing I did was follow Sanchit's answer: `sudo apt-get install libgcc1 libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libpcrecpp0 python mysql-workbench-data` But I tried again to install in through Ubuntu Software Center and got the same error. But now, I don't know if that was a necessary step or not. At that point I tried through the command line, with the mindset that it was just a matter of installing the right packages to meet dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I did `sudo apt-get update` after adding the APT and workbench installed but couldn't work. I ran this command:

`sudo apt-get -f install` and re-installed with

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community
```

and it worked.